# Пронумировать даты в разных категориях

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

У меня есть датафрейм примерного вида:

```
a_list = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
day_list = ['2008-09-02', 
            '2008-09-02', 
            '2008-09-05',
            '2008-09-05',
            '2009-09-01', 
            '2009-09-02', 
            '2009-09-02',
            '2009-09-07']
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat': a_list, 'day': day_list})
df

    cat day
0   A   2008-09-02
1   A   2008-09-02
2   A   2008-09-05
3   A   2008-09-05
4   B   2009-09-01
5   B   2009-09-02
6   B   2009-09-02
7   B   2009-09-07
```

Я должен получить новый столбец, в котором дни будут пронумерованы по порядку в каждой категории. Вот так:

```
df['num_day'] = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3]
df

    cat day num_day
0   A   2008-09-02  1
1   A   2008-09-02  1
2   A   2008-09-05  2
3   A   2008-09-05  2
4   B   2009-09-01  1
5   B   2009-09-02  2
6   B   2009-09-02  2
7   B   2009-09-07  3
```

Пробовал использовать pd.factorize(), но он пронумеровал все от 0 и до конца не обращая внимание на категорию.
Заранее спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 3):

```
df['num_day'] = df.groupby('cat').rank(method='dense').astype(int)
print(df)
```

```
  cat         day  num_day
0   A  2008-09-02        1
1   A  2008-09-02        1
2   A  2008-09-05        2
3   A  2008-09-05        2
4   B  2009-09-01        1
5   B  2009-09-02        2
6   B  2009-09-02        2
7   B  2009-09-07        3
```